# waveInClose/Reset/Stop - no msg

Tags: windows, audio

I'm doing audio sampling with waveInProc callback. The problem is that when I'm trying to stop sampling and close the audio device I get no msg in the callback - tried waveInStop, waveInClose, waveInReset.

Pls advice.
10xs,
Nahum

```
HWAVEIN  hWaveIn
waveInOpen(&hWaveIn,WAVE_MAPPER,&waveform,(DWORD)waveInProc,0, CALLBACK_FUNCTION);
waveInStart(hWaveIn);

waveInStop(hWaveIn); //OR
waveInClose(hWaveIn); //OR
waveInReset(hWaveIn); //OR
```

UPDATE: Here is the code:

Starting:

```
waveInOpen(&hWaveIn,WAVE_MAPPER,&waveform,(DWORD)waveInProc,0, CALLBACK_FUNCTION);
waveInPrepareHeader(hWaveIn,pWaveHdr1,sizeof(WAVEHDR));
waveInAddBuffer(hWaveIn,pWaveHdr1,sizeof(WAVEHDR));
waveInStart(hWaveIn);
```

---

```
 void CALLBACK waveInProc(  HWAVEIN hwi, UINT uMsg, DWORD dwInstance, 
                            DWORD dwParam1,   DWORD       dwParam2    )
  {

     if (uMsg == WIM_OPEN)
     {
     return;
     }
     if (uMsg == WIM_DATA)
     {
     //process data
     waveInAddBuffer(hWaveIn,(PWAVEHDR)dwParam1,sizeof(WAVEHDR));
     return;
     }
     if (uMsg == WIM_CLOSE) //NOT GETTING THIS MSG

     {
      printf("*****************got WIM_CLOSE\n");
     }
 }
```

---

So how to stop sampling and close the audio device?

---

Here is the code:
Starting:

```
waveInOpen(&hWaveIn,WAVE_MAPPER,&waveform,(DWORD)waveInProc,0, CALLBACK_FUNCTION);
waveInPrepareHeader(hWaveIn,pWaveHdr1,sizeof(WAVEHDR));
waveInAddBuffer(hWaveIn,pWaveHdr1,sizeof(WAVEHDR));
waveInStart(hWaveIn);
```

---

```
 void CALLBACK waveInProc(  HWAVEIN hwi, UINT uMsg, DWORD dwInstance, 
                            DWORD dwParam1,   DWORD       dwParam2    )
  {

     if (uMsg == WIM_OPEN)
     {
     return;
     }
     if (uMsg == WIM_DATA)
     {
     //process data
     waveInAddBuffer(hWaveIn,(PWAVEHDR)dwParam1,sizeof(WAVEHDR));
     return;
     }
     if (uMsg == WIM_CLOSE) //NOT GETTING THIS MSG

     {
      printf("*****************got WIM_CLOSE\n");
     }
 }
```

---

So how to stop sampling and close the audio device?

10xs,
Nahum

Comment: Roman - I edited the question with code

Comment: Note that you are not supoposed to do `waveInAddBuffer` from the callback. From MSDN: "Calling other wave functions [there] will cause deadlock".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you checking your `waveInOpen` result?

Because it works as expected:

```
hWaveIn 0x005B7768, nMessage 0x03BE, nInstance 0, nParameter1 0, nParameter2 0
nWaveInOpenResult 0, hWaveIn 0x005B7768
hWaveIn 0x005B7768, nMessage 0x03BF (WIM_CLOSE), nInstance 0, nParameter1 0, nParameter2 0
```

Code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <mmsystem.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "winmm.lib")

VOID CALLBACK waveInProc(HWAVEIN hWaveIn, UINT nMessage, DWORD_PTR nInstance, DWORD_PTR nParameter1, DWORD_PTR nParameter2)
{
    _tprintf(_T("hWaveIn 0x%p, nMessage 0x%04X, nInstance %d, nParameter1 %d, nParameter2 %d\n"), hWaveIn, nMessage, nInstance, nParameter1, nParameter2);
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    WAVEFORMATEX Format = { WAVE_FORMAT_PCM, 1, 8000, 16000, 2, 16, 0 };
    HWAVEIN hWaveIn = NULL;
    const MMRESULT nWaveInOpenResult = waveInOpen(&hWaveIn, WAVE_MAPPER, &Format, (DWORD_PTR) &waveInProc, 0, CALLBACK_FUNCTION);
    _tprintf(_T("nWaveInOpenResult %d, hWaveIn 0x%p\n"), nWaveInOpenResult, hWaveIn);
    waveInStart(hWaveIn);
    waveInStop(hWaveIn);
    waveInClose(hWaveIn);
    return 0;
}
```

While processing data in real code make sure to take this into consideration: [within the callback function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd743849%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> Applications **should not call** any system-defined functions from inside
>   a callback function, except for EnterCriticalSection,
>   LeaveCriticalSection, midiOutLongMsg, midiOutShortMsg,
>   OutputDebugString, PostMessage, PostThreadMessage, SetEvent,
>   timeGetSystemTime, timeGetTime, timeKillEvent, and timeSetEvent.
>   **Calling other wave functions will cause deadlock**.

To re-add buffer, you need to indicate such as need by signalling to another thread, using `PostMessage` or `SetEvent`, so that your code outside of the callback could receive this indication and re-add the empty buffer from there.

Comment: Beside the closing part it is working OK, the waveInProc is being called again and again with uMsg == WIM_DATA

Comment: Which means you don't stop capture, nevertheless you think you do (like in your question). Post real code.

Comment: 10xs Roman. waveInStop(hWaveIn) returns MMSYSERR_NOERROR. Afterwards I'm calling waveInClose and the program crash  - there is a lot of code, what would you like to see?

Comment: You are doing something wrong, and nobody knows what because there is no real code. Try to cut reasonable amount of capturing code to show the problem, or what is also likely by doing so you will see the problem yourself. If you have crash, perhaps you need to start from it.